# What is MySQL's correct syntax for before delete trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

I'd like to create a before delete trigger that deletes rows from two different tables. But I can't figure out which parameters to use.

I got a house table, and when I delete a row, I'd like to delete every row in my two other tables: user_house and firm_house, which contains same house id as the one triggering the event.

What does `FOR EACH ROW` mean? And how can I properly set my trigger up?

```
USE `mydb`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `deleteUnions` BEFORE DELETE ON `house` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM user_house WHERE ?? = ??; 
    DELETE FROM firm_house WHERE ?? = ??;
END
```

Some details about the structure:

- `user_house` is joined by `user_id` and `house_id`;
- `firm_houise` is joined by `firm_id` and `house_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the record that gets deleted in the trigger with `OLD`. Then use the `id` to delete from the other tables.

```
DELETE FROM user_house WHERE house_id = OLD.house_id; 
DELETE FROM firm_house WHERE house_id = OLD.house_id;
```

Comment: I get "ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'id' in 'OLD'" when trying to Apply?

Comment: How does your tables look like? Does your `house` table not have an `id` column? And has `user_house` a `house_id` column?

Comment: I got it to work, old.house_id;. Thanks alot for the help  :)